# Разбиение массива на подмассивы

Tags: php, массивы, парсер

У меня есть php массив примерно с таким содержанием:

```
  Array (
        [service_id] => 5
        [service_name] => Service name
        [branch_name] => Branch name
        [branch_address] => Branch address
        [branch_phone] => +7 (950) 555-55-55
        [company_id] => 16
        [company_type] => ООО
        [company_email] => email@bk.ru
        [company_phone] => +7 (911) 555-00-00
        [company_name] => Company name
  )
```

Задача распарсить массив до такого вида:

```
  Array (
        [service] => Array(
              [id] => 5
              [name] => Service name
        )
        [branch] => Array(
              [name] => Branch name
              [address] => Branch address
              [phone] => +7 (950) 555-55-55
        )
        [company] => Array(
              [id] => 16
              [type] => ООО
              [email] => email@bk.ru
              [phone] => +7 (911) 555-00-00
              [name] => Company name
        )
  )
```

Есть ли в PHP встроенные средства для выполнения подобной задачи или нужно писать свою функцию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перебирай и разделяй!

```
$array = array(
    'service_id' => 5,
    'service_name' => 'Service name',
    'branch_name' => 'Branch name',
    'branch_address' => 'Branch address',
    'branch_phone' => '+7 (950) 555-55-55',
    'company_id' => 16,
    'company_type' => 'ООО',
    'company_email' => 'email@bk.ru',
    'company_phone' => '+7 (911) 555-00-00',
    'company_name' => 'Company name',
);
$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    list($e1, $e2) = explode('_', $key, 2);
    $newArray[$e1][$e2] = $value;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Вот, идеально. Я примерно то же решение использовал, только не знал, что у explode есть третий аргумент) Спасибо большое за решение

Answer (score 1):

Придется циклом самому писать. Под такое извращение готовой функции нет.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть это у вас из формы такой массив приходит, то можно в форме сформировать правильный массив:

```
<input name="service[id]" value="5" />
<input name="service[name]" value="Service name" />
<input name="branch[name]" value="Branch name" />
...
```

и так далее.

Comment: Не форма, а выборка из базы данных. Про этот трюк я знаю